# Decimate vertices from an edge not attached to any face

Tags: particles, vertices, edges, hair, retopology

i have converted a hair particle in Blender to Mesh, the hair turned to edges containing many vertices, when i try the decimate modifier, i get an error because there is no faces, is there any way to delete or unsubdivide or dissolve those vertex, and make each edge has only 2 o 4 vertex those edges

thank you

Comment: Maybe try the X > Limited Dissolve?